# Inserting columns into numpy arrays based on Boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Apologies if this question has an elementary answer, but I have not been able to find one yet.

I have some data that was originally a `numpy` array of shape `(N, M)`, but where certain columns have then been removed. For illustration lets say `M=6` and 2 columns where removed, leaving a `(N, 4)` array. What I also have is an array denoting whether a column was kept or not with a Boolean value (`True` if kept, `False` if not), e.g. `array([False,  True,  True,  False,  True,  True])`.

What I would like to do would be to reconstruct an `(N, 6)` array from the `(N, 4)` array and the boolean markers, with the columns reintroduced at the right index (filled with zeros).

Any help on the requisite slicing etc approaches would be valued!

Comment: You should be able to make a new array with `np.insert`, using `[0, 3]`, insert positions as an argument.  But read its docs.  But it isn't hard to create a new array directly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
# original array -- for references only
arr = np.arange(12).reshape(-1,6)

# keep indexes
keep = np.array([False,  True,  True,  False,  True,  True])

# array after removing the columns
removed_arr = arr[:,keep]

# output array
out = np.zeros((removed_arr.shape[0], len(keep)), dtype=removed_arr.dtype)

# copy the values of `removed_arr` to output
out[:, keep] = removed_arr
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  7,  8,  0, 10, 11]])
```